# this.href not returning href

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am not sure if it is because I am using Wordpress but the `this.href` is not returning the href on the items that have them (for example on "contact" it returns http://www.domain.net/undefined opposed to http://www.domain.net/contact). If I remove the script the nav loads the href just fine.

Here is the JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#page-wrap').delay(500).fadeIn(1000);

      $(".menu-item").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        $("#page-wrap").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);        
    });

    function redirectPage() {
        window.location = linkLocation;
    }
});
```

Here is the php wordpress file

```
<div id="nav_wrap">
        <div id="nav"><?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu',) ); ?></div>
    </div>
```

Here is what wordpress returns in html format

```
<div id="nav_wrap">
        <div id="nav"><div class="menu-main-container"><ul id="menu-main" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-13" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-13"><a href="http://www.domain.net">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-28"><a>Company</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-32" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-32"><a href="http://www.domain.net/jobs/">Careers</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-29"><a>Portfolio</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-65" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-65"><a href="http://www.domain.net/breweries/">Breweries</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-30"><a>Retailer Resources</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-31" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-31"><a>Community</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-15" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-15"><a href="http://www.domain.net/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul></div></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `event.target.href` instead of `this.href`? I'm not sure, but `this` could refer to the `li` and not to the `a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are running the selector on `.menu-item` which is a `<li>`. It has no href attribute.

You need the select the `<a>` tag inside your `<li>` tag. This should do it:

```
$(".menu-item a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    linkLocation = this.href;
    $("#page-wrap").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);        
});
```

A bonus of doing this vs. the other answers of selecting `<li>` and then the child `<a>` is that this will only run when the user clicks the actual link. The others will run when anywhere in the `<li>` is clicked, which depending on your CSS, could be outside the actual link space.

[jsFiddle with working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ney47/)

Comment: @Connor the `href` attribute is native to the browser. It is not a jQuery construct. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: @Ken Don't appease him by replying to him, he's just being facetious. Just flag his comments and ignore the troll.

Comment: @John I didnt even think about that. Thanks!! And thanks to all who posted.

Answer (score 1):

`Menu item` is not returning the href because it's an `<li/>`.

You need to target the `<a>` child element of the menu item.

`linkLocation = $(this).children('a').attr('href');`

Comment: This forces the selection to go into two steps, as well as it runs when anywhere in the `<li>` space instead of only directly on the link. This might defy user expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Change `linkLocation = this.href;` to `linkLocation = $(this).attr('href');` or if that does not work try `linkLocation = $(this).find('a').attr('href');`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery you might want to go all jQuery:

```
linkLocation = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `href` property is only associated with the `<a>` tags, but the click event is being added to the `<li>` tags. Change your code to `$(".menu-item a").click ...`